# Is the gameplay the same throughout the main series?

Tags: dynasty-warriors

is the series of Dynasty warriors' gameplay the same throughout (the main series such as dynasty warriors 1, 2, 3 and so on excluding Dynasty Tactics) or is there one that has a different playing style? I have dynasty warriors 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 and the gameplay seems identical but with new characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core gameplay in Dynasty Warriors is basically the same throughout the series. There are usually new/modified tactical gameplay mechanics added in each version but usually it is not that different from each other.

**Core gameplay:** Get into battle and finish the objective as defined. Defeating officers usually yields stat points to the character.

**Character Progression**: Stat increase by battling and collecting stat ups. Chance to meet new followers who would join you. Experience gained by followers to level up and become more powerful.

**Weapon Upgrades**: Usually 3-4 tiers of weapons for each character that unlock longer combos.

**Overall Game Progress**: Unlock items by completing objectives or missions. Also unlock mission maps and characters by finishing storyline with other characters.

There are slight differences and additions in each version to the above formula but is essentially the same.

Comment: So, it's pretty much comparable with Fifa/Madden/COD xD

Comment: Well, yeah pretty much :P

Comment: I disagree with COD and FIFA and I've never heard of Madden purely because the maps are at least noticeably different and the gameplay can sustain my interest for more than 20 minutes, unlike fifa where its a green field and little colour coded men running about for 90 minutes... haha I play DW when I fancy a good button mash.. stress relief at its best

Comment: @NathanTaylor you do realize that this was a joke, right?

Answer (score 1):

Samyam's answer is correct for all instalments starting with Dynasty Warriors 2, but the original [Dynasty Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynasty_Warriors_(video_game)) was a one-on-one beat-em-up and not a hack-and-slash like the rest of the series.